# How to remove inline css applied by smart gwt automatically

Tags: css, smartgwt

When i created a dynamic form used by smart gwt then many `<div>` or `<table>` tags are automatically created with inline css already applied[![enter image description here][1]][1] because of this when i apply my css on that widget.
That CSS is applied on internal `<div>` or outernal `<div>`, not on particular widget. so How can i apply (external) css on that particular widget.

Answer (score 0):

Look for attributes of DynamicForm and FormItem(s) with 'style' in the name. 
You can provide your own CSS (use the original definitions as a reference)